Getting error in JSP The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
In Websphere Application Server -8.5 getting below error :
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
Framework - ead4j(similar to struts)
I tried adding below code in Web.xml, but it didn't worked:

   
> <servlet>
>        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
>             <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
>          <init-param>
>           <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
>           <param-value>false</param-value>
>          </init-param>
>  
>    </servlet>
> 

